# Does the following pattern is good for dealing with client state on a server?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, server

I have the following pattern for many module/service/class on my server code:

```
class Sercice1PerClient
{
    void method1(int i)
    {
        printf("%s", StateOfTheClient);
    }
    void method2(int i)
    {
        printf("foo %s bar", StateOfTheClient);
    }
    char *StateOfTheClient;
}

class Service1
{
    void method1(int i, int clientID)
    {
        v[clientID].method1(i);
    }
    void method2(int i, int clientID)
    {
        v[clientID].method2(i);
    }
    std::vector<Sercice1PerClient> v
}
```

The problem I face is every time I want to change `method1` I have to do it 4 times (2 in the cpp and 2 in the header)

Is there any better way to keep the state of each client separate from each other without having to repeat all the functions in the "mother class"?

Does this pattern has a name and do you think it's reasonable?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way for this without marching deeply into meta-programming territoy (and thats definitely not solving anything here); and even then this shouldnt be possible. You can however templatize the code above by using parameter packs and `std::forward`. This should atleast remove some redundancy,

Answer (score 0):

First, please don't use `char *`. This is c++. Use `string` or `stringview`.

Next, how about an array of client information, including the current status? I don't know if that solves your problem, but keeping `status of c1` and `status of c2` as distinct variables seems repetitive.

Comment: I was just using char * to represent state but this can be any type and any number of members depending on the Service I implement. I think the problem is that the architecture is done in layer and layer 3 needs the function of layer 1 so layer 2 needs to forward the functions...